# Titanium Android Simple Form Creation

Tags: android, forms, titanium

Im a Titanium Beginner who is trying to create a form page with 2 textfields of Name and address and a DateTimePicker. I am facing 2 problems right now being :

1) the DateTimePicker is successfully shown but i would like both of it and also including the 2 textfields to be on the same window, with a same submit button.

2) I have tried numerous times but am unable to create a simple textfield at all even just creating it on a single page.It just doesnt show up.
Anyone could offer some constructive help?

Thanks in advance. The Below is my current code.

var winTimePicker = Titanium.UI.createWindow({});
    winTimePicker.backgroundColor = 'black';

```
var doneBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Done',
});

doneBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    winTimePicker.hide();
});

winTimePicker.add(doneBtn);

var timePicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_TIME,
    bottom:0,
});


// turn on the selection indicator (off by default)
timePicker.selectionIndicator = true;

timePicker.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    //your code
});

winTimePicker.add(timePicker);


//open window
winTimePicker.open();
```

var winDatePicker = Titanium.UI.createWindow({});
    winDatePicker.backgroundColor = 'black';

```
var doneBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Done',
});

doneBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    winDatePicker.hide();
});

winDatePicker.add(doneBtn);

var datePicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
    bottom:0,
});


// turn on the selection indicator (off by default)
datePicker.selectionIndicator = true;

datePicker.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    //your code
});

winDatePicker.add(datePicker);


//open window
winDatePicker.open();
```

var textField = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    width:"auto",
    height:"auto",
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
});

var textField2 = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    width:"auto",
    height:"auto",
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code out and make changes as you find suitable to it:

```
var timePickerWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            navBarHidden : true,
            backgroundColor : '#fff'
        });

var startTime = Ti.UI.createPicker({
        top : '15dp',
        left : '50dp',
        useSpinner : false,
        selectionIndicator : true,
        type : Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_TIME,
        format24 : false,
        height : '130dp',
        //  width:'auto'

    });


 var endTime = Ti.UI.createPicker({
            top : '15dp',
            left : '50dp',
            useSpinner : false,
            selectionIndicator : true,
            type : Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_TIME,
            format24 : false,
            height : '130dp'
        });

var nextButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
            width : '220dp',
            height : '45dp',
            top : '15dp',
            title : 'Next',
            backgroundColor : '#294079',
            font : {
                fontSize : '18dp',
                fontWeight : 'bold'
            },
            color : '#fff'
        });

startTime.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        //alert("User selected date: " + e.value);
        startPickerValue = e.value;
    });

    endTime.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        //alert("User selected date: " + e.value);
        endPickerValue = e.value
    });
var fullNameTextBox = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        borderStyle : Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
        width : '275dp',
        height : '45dp',
        //value : '',
        top : '15dp',
        color : '#000000',
        hintText : 'Enter full name'
        //  backGroundColor:'gray',

    });
    var emailTextBox = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        borderStyle : Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
        width : '275dp',
        height : '45dp',
        //value : '',
        top : '15dp',
        color : '#000000',
        hintText : 'Enter email'

    });
```

Finally add all these UI elements to the window which is the timePickerWin using add function

```
timePickerWin.add(startTime);
```

and so on for all the UI elements.After that open the timePickerWin as below

```
timePickerWin.open()
```

Make suitable layout changes by varying the left,right,height and width properties of each element.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mukund! works out fine but only one of the textboxes show up.Why is that?

Comment: The UI elements are overlapping each other. Is there any way to format them?

Comment: Hi Jayden,All you have to do is make changes to the top property of each UI element.For example in the above example make changes to the top property of the Text Fields and you will be fine(2 Text fields will appear).Please accept this  as an answer if it has helped you.Thanks.